# c# - query nested type with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model that looks like the following:

```
public class MyType{
 public string Id {get;set;}
 public string Name{get;set;}
 public List<MyType> Children{get;set;}
}
```

and in my data I have just two level data, meaning my objects will look like:

```
{
 MyType{"1","firstParent",
 {
  MyType{"2","firstChild",null},
  MyType{"3","secondChild",null}}
 },

 MyType{"4","secondParent",
 {
  MyType{"5","firstChild",null},
  MyType{"6","secondChild",null}}
 }
}
```

How do I query to get MyType object with a specific Id where it might be a parent or child?

The following will return only parents.

```
collection.FirstOrDefault(c => c.id==id)
```

Comment: Usually you have an *Id* and a *ParentId* in your database, so that you can build a tree from that. I can't see these information anywhere in your data?

Comment: what makes you think that my database is a sql database?

Comment: I don't assume that. It doesn't matter what kind of database you have, somewhere you have to define the hierarchy of your objects.

Comment: What is name of property that type is `List<MyType>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build a list of all MyType including children and then query on it like this :

```
collection.SelectMany(c => c.Children).Concat(collection).Where(c => c.id == id)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Any` with a recursive local function to find objects on any level (your data structure would seem to indicate a deeper level is possible)

```
bool hasIdOrChildren(MyType t, string localId)
{
    return t.Id == localId || (t.Children != null && t.Children.Any(o => hasIdOrChildren(o, localId)));
}
collection.FirstOrDefault(c => hasIdOrChildren(c, id));
```

Or using pre C#7 syntax:

```
Func<MyType, string, bool> hasIdOrChildren = null;
hasIdOrChildren = (MyType t, string localId) =>
{
    return t.Id == localId || (t.Children != null && t.Children.Any(o => hasIdOrChildren(o, localId)));
};
collection.FirstOrDefault(c => hasIdOrChildren(c, id));
```

If you are only interested in one level, you can drop the reclusiveness:

```
collection.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id || (c.Children != null && c.Children.Any(o => o.Id == id)));
```

**Edit**

The code above gives the parent if any child has the id, you can also flatten the whole tree structure using `SelectMany` also with a recursive function:

```
IEnumerable<MyType> flattenTree(MyType t)
{
    if(t.Children == null)
    {
        return new[] { t };
    }
    return new[] { t }
        .Concat(t.Children.SelectMany(flattenTree));
};
collection
    .SelectMany(flattenTree)
    .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
```

This method can be useful for any type of processing where you need to flatten the tree.

Comment: This will return only parent objects no ? Does'nt he want child objects to be returned if they have the right id ?

Comment: @OnyxCaldin Yes, my bad, I didn't get that at first .. added a version for that too, 10x :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for

```
var flattenedList = IEnumerable.SelectMany(i => i.ItemsInList);
```

This flattens the list and gives back one list with all items in it.
In your case you need to select

```
collection.SelectMany(c => c.Type).Concat(collection).Where(item => item.Id == 5);
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx)

You still got the childs in your joined parents here, but you can still erase them or ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should flatten `collection` using [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.110).aspx) method, then use `FirstOrDefault` to get element by `id`:

```
MyType selected = collection
    .SelectMany(obj => new MyType[] {obj, obj.NestedList})
    .FirstOrDefault(obj => obj.id == id);
```